# Angular: using both *ngFor and *ngIf with reference to index value in child elements

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I would like to **render objects** from array observable in some grid-car components. In addition, I want to limit the number of grid cards to a value based on variables in my component i.e. `gridCols*maxRows` using `*ngIf` condition checking.

I know that it is not possible to use both `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` simultaneously on the same element. So I need to use `<template ngFor ...>`
to wrap my grid-card elements which will be conditionally rendered based on `*ngFor`. Given this, how I can reference `index` or `content` variables from `*ngFor` in `*ngIf`.

```
<template ngFor let-content [ngForOf]="contentObjectsObservable | async" let-i="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
    <grid-card *ngIf="i < gridCols*maxRows" [content]="content" [style.width.%]="gridCardWidth"></grid-card>
</template>
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried something like this

```
 #i="index"
```

with such error message:

> There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "index"

Comment: I'd suggest the slice pipe for limiting max rows  (or actually max items) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-pipe.html

Comment: It's ok but I would like to also know how I could reference index and content variables of ngFor loop in the child element <grid-card> it could also be useful

Comment: I don't know what `<grid-card>` is. If it's a component you built, just add inputs like `@Input() index:int; @Input() content:SomeType;` and then pass it like `<grid-card *ngIf="i < gridCols*maxRows" [index]="i" [content]="content"`

Comment: so can I define `let-i="index"` and then use in grid-card component this statement `*ngIf="i < gridCols*maxRows"`. I have thought it doesn't work as my elements never hides

Comment: It should work. `#i="index"` is outdated and is not supported since almost a year. `let-i="index"` is the correct form. You can also use `<ng-container *ngFor="let content of contentObjectsObservable | async; let i=index">` instead of `<template ...>` to be able use the more common syntax but with the same result.

Comment: So I don't know why *ngIf doesn't hide element when index i is greater then allowed number of rows and cols

Comment: Try to debug it by writing `{{ i }}` front of `<grid-card`. You can also check `{{gridCols*maxRows}}`

Comment: ok I've tried something like this `*ngIf="i < 3"` and it worked for me to hide more then 3 elements, so there is some bug in `gridCols*maxRows`

Comment: Yes, this `gridCols*maxRows` to huge number. I don't know why I have to inspect it.

Answer (score 8):

You can reference the index from *ngFor by putting `let i = index` in the *ngFor statement!
Example:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="i < (gridCols * maxRows)" class="row">
    <grid-card [content]="content" [style.width.%]="gridCardWidth"></grid-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Make sure that you have defined gridCols and maxRows as numbers in your component!

```
gridCols:number = <your number>;
maxRows:number = <your number>;
```

Hope this helps!